# Compare two same object value which is present in HashMap in drools rule

Tags: java, hashmap, drools

Attribute class that contains key and value:

```
public class Attribute {

    private String key;
    private String value;
//setter and getter method
}
```

Main class

```
public class DroolsMain {

    public static HashMap<String , Attribute> hashMapAttribute = new HashMap<String , Attribute>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DroolsParserException, IOException {
        String Keys[] = {"From" , "To" , "Subject" };
String attributesValues[] = { "Sathish" ,"aranjan" , "email" };   
       for(int i =0;i<Keys.length;i++)
        {
            Attribute attribute = new Attribute();
            attribute.setKey(Keys[i]);
            attribute.setValue(attributesValues[i]);
            hashMapAttribute.put("" + i, attribute);
        }    
//...
workingMemory.insert(hashMapAttribute);
   }
}
```

In rule.drl file, I want to compare key-value of an object with another similar type of object which present in HashMap.

rule.drl

```
rule "Rule 1:" 

   when 
        $mapAttribute : Map()
        $entry : Entry() from $mapAttribute.entrySet()
        $attribute : Attribute() from $entry.getValue() 
        $attribute1 : Attribute(this != $attribute) from $entry.getValue() 
        Boolean(booleanValue == true) from (($attribute.getKey contains("From") && $attribute.getValue contains("Sathish")) && ($attribute1.getKey contains("Subject") && $attribute1.getValue contains("email")))

     then
        System.out.println("Rule 1 run successfully ");     
    end
```

How I compare two object value. Please Help me to find solution.

Answer (score 1):

I get a solution from changing rule.drl file:

```
rule "Rule 1:" 

   when 
        $mapAttribute : Map()
        $entry : Entry() from $mapAttribute.entrySet()
        $attribute : Attribute() from $entry.getValue() 
        $mapAttribute1 : Map()
        $entry1 : Entry() from $mapAttribute1.entrySet()
        $attribute1 : Attribute() from $entry1.getValue() 
        Boolean(booleanValue == true) from (($attribute.getKey contains("From") && $attribute.getValue contains("Sathish")) && ($attribute1.getKey contains("Subject") && $attribute1.getValue contains("email")))

     then
        System.out.println("Rule 1 run successfully ");

    end
```